# Can a college access your Tor browsing history?

Tags: anonymity, security

It is well known that a college that you are attending has access to your browsing history. Does Tor prevent this injustice?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the computer is yours, then no, they can't access your browsing history. They can know you are using Tor though.

Comment: If you don't want your college to know you are using Tor you might want to access Tor using [bridges](https://bridges.torproject.org/).

Answer (score 0):

No.  All they can see are outgoing requests to the Tor network.  These can be blocked though, so be warned.  Use multiple no-log VPN's that change every few hours for the best result.